# Simple SpringBoot application works in eclipse, throws exception from terminal

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, exception, terminal

I have a very simple SpringBoot application:

HelloConfig.java:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HelloConfig {

    @RequestMapping("/time")
    public String time() {
        return "time is " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'HelloConfig'
    }
}
```

The app works in eclipse, but when I run it from the terminal:

```
gradle build
java -Dserver.port=8080 -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at HelloConfig.main(HelloConfig.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

How can I execute this application from a unix terminal?

Comment: You're not applying an spring plugin allowing to create a single eecutable jar containing all the dependencies, and you're executing the jar conaining only your classes, without having all theother dependencies in the classpath. How could that work? As always, it's always simpler when you read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-gradle. You could also use start.spring.io, which would generate a correct build file for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the springboot plugin to your `build.gradle` file like:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

and then from the command line you can run it by typing:

```
gradle bootRun
```

or if you use the gradle wrapper

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

In general if you are starting a new spring boot project and you want to use gradle as a build system (highly recommended!!!) then it's best to get go to [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io) and select gradle (don't know why they default to maven still!) and it will have the correct build.gradle file with the springboot plugin included.

The amazing thing about gradle is you can ask it to tell you all of the tasks it thinks it knows about via:

```
gradle tasks --all
```

so if you are ever wondering if there is a particular argument you can give to gradle to accomplish a certain tasks then this will tell you what is currently available given the plugins that have been configured in your `build.gradle` file.